# MySQL - #1051 - Unknown table 'userchat'

Tags: mysql, corruption

I have a local database that I need to drop and reload a new version in.
The drop hanged for a long time, couldn't restart WAMP so I restarted my PC.

Now the database is empty except for one table and it says:

> #1051 - Unknown table 'userchat'

I've tried lots of ways to drop this table with no luck.
eg: I tried phpMyAdmin GUI stuff and drop table blah and drop database blah etc.

Is there a trick to removing a database in this situation?
I can remove and re-install WAMP if I need to.

Comment: can you repair/optimize the database?

Comment: gonegr_db.userchat optimize Error Failed to read from the .par file
gonegr_db.userchat optimize Error Incorrect information in file: '.\gonegr_db\userch...
gonegr_db.userchat optimize error Corrupt

Comment: no I get corrupt on repair and optimize for the table... I'll look to see if I can do it on the database rather then table level

Comment: Can you drop the whole database?

Comment: no I can't drop the database... error about the corrupt table...

Comment: Error
SQL query: 

DROP DATABASE  `gonegr_db`

MySQL said: 

#1051 - Unknown table 'userchat'

Comment: yet I can see the table still there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysqlcheck` — A Table Maintenance Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) and than again try to `drop database`:

```
mysqlcheck --auto-repair --databases gonegr_db --user=your_username --password
```

Comment: Enter password:
gonegr_db.userchat
Error    : Failed to read from the .par file
Error    : Incorrect information in file: '.\gonegr_db\userchat.frm'
error    : Corrupt

Repairing tables
gonegr_db.userchat
Error    : Failed to read from the .par file
Error    : Incorrect information in file: '.\gonegr_db\userchat.frm'
error    : Corrupt